# How to handle general exceptions in Asp.Net MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, exception

I want to transfer all unhandled exceptions to an error page in Asp.Net MVC. What is the way to handle the unhandled exceptions in Asp.net MVC? Is there anything like application_error?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

check out the HandleError attribute. There's a good write up [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/07/14/asp-net-mvc-preview-4-release-part-1.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the standard setup, your controller(s) can do this by overriding one of the methods (proabably `OnException`, but I don't have it handy to check). If you want all your controllers to share this logic, you can use a base-controller.

Alternatively, you can do this via filters (for example `[HandleError]`). I don't know if there is a single global place for such logic, though.

Comment: I have a base controller. I guess it is enough to put this filter to base class. Am I right?